# Next.js useRouter with useEffect pushes even if condition is met on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, react-context, next-router

I am running into an issue with `useRouter` and `useEffect` where I want to re-direct the user if a certain condition is not met.

On page 1 you select an `amount` which is passed into a context and is retrieved on page 2.

On page 2 I have this condition:

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import AppContext from "../context/AppContext";

const PageTwo = () => {
  const { amount } = useContext(AppContext);
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!amount || amount == null) {
      router.push("/page-1"); // redirect if no amount is selected
    }
  });

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

When we land on page 2 I have the `amount` but when you do a page refresh it directs you back to `page-1` even when there is an `amount` set. It works fine when you go straight to `page-2`, without selecting an amount on `page-1`, it re-directs you back to `page-2`.

I might be getting something wrong here in how the Context API and or useRouter and useEffect work in this case.

**Here is a CodeSanBox example with the issue:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-userouter-with-useeffect-6645u?file=/pages/page-2.js

Comment: If you persist "amount" state in "AppContext" and a user do a page refresh, "amount" state will be it's default value. Are you sure of this? "when you do a page refresh it directs you back to page-1 even when there is an amount set."

Comment: Exactly. Even when there is an `amount` set, on page refresh on `page-2` it directs back to `page-1`. When console logging amount you can see it is there. Maybe I'll setup a quick CodeSandBox to elaborate myself more.

Comment: You get undefined for a split second causing the redirect back to page-1.

Comment: It is weird because when the amount is set, it is being stored in localStorage as well. Any idea on how to fix this? Perhaps there is a better approach to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour occurs because even after setting a new `amount` value in context, when reloading the page its initial value will be `null` on first render which happens before the app checks and sets the `localStorage` value. This triggers the redirect *before* the `setAmount(amount)` is called with the stored value from `localStorage`.

To prevent this with minimal changes, you could modify the check that triggers the redirect to the following. Making sure to also add `amount` to the `useEffect`'s dependencies array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (amount === "") {
        router.push("/page-1");
    }
}, [amount]);
```

You'd also have to change the value passed to `setAmount` in `_app` to default to empty string if no value is stored.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const amount = localStorage.getItem("amount") ?? "";
    setAmount(amount);
}, []);
```

This allows us to have a different values for the initial state value (`null`) and empty value (`""`). Meaning the redirect will not happen before `amount` is updated with the value stored in `localStorage`.

Finally, to keep the logic consistent, you have to update the `clearAmount` function to set `amount` to the empty value.

```js
const clearAmount = () => {
    setAmount("");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change null to an empty string `("")` instead of `(null)` in your `clearAmount` function and in `useState("")` in the _app file. Also, change your if statement to `if (amount === "")`. That fixes it, here's a sandbox that I forked from yours. https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-userouter-with-useeffect-forked-t2enf?file=/pages/page-2.js

Comment: I think we are almost there. The problem is that on a 'fresh' page visit you are still able to visit `page-2` directly and stays on `page-2` and displays: `The amount is: null`. Instead it should re-direct back to `page-1` as well.

Comment: Add the same empty string to useState("") in the _app. I updated the answer..

Comment: I hate to be the bringer of bad news, but now when you select an amount on `page-1` then on `page-2` refresh the page. It will re-direct you back to `page-1`